# Regarding top down development in webservice for apache cxf

Tags: java, web-services, spring, cxf

I was following this url  http://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/jaxwscxf_step2/ in which bottom up development is shown. Please advise for url in which top down approach is also shown in a similar way, as I have wsdl with me I need to test them with cxf and java.

For client I have found the following url also http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-pojo-springcxf/ but please advise for more url.